# Default value of dropdown box not showing in Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular, dropdownbox

I am trying to display "Select a color" as the default value in my dropdown box. After selecting the color I want this option to not be available.

Below is the code I am using:

```
<select class="color-filter" [(ngModel)] = "selectedColor">
     <option disabled selected value class="hideoption">Select a Color</option>
     <option *ngFor="let c of color | mapToIterable" [value]="c.key">{{c.val}}</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
 .hideoption { display:none; visibility:hidden; height:0; font-size:0; }
```

Without including ngModel this works fine. However when I include ngModel it shows no default text in my dropdown box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the model `selectedColor` is empty, and angular select the option selected in the ngModel, in your case is `undefined`, and angular search that value and it don't found nothing.

You should put a default value to the default option and put that value to the model.

Like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <select class="color-filter" [(ngModel)] = "selectedColor">
     <option disabled value="0" class="hideoption">Select a Color</option>
     <option *ngFor="let c of color" [value]="c">{{c}}</option>
</select>  
  `,
  styles: [`
  .hideoption { display:none; visibility:hidden; height:0; font-size:0; }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedColor:any = 0;
  color;

  constructor(){
    this.color = [
      "red","blue"
    ]
  }
}
```

You can seem it in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RuncX54NfV2VMHTKMK45?p=preview), enjoy.